# Do we ever hear from O'Brien's 'dog' again?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

[The Forsaken](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Forsaken_%28episode%29) details the incursion of an electronic being into DS9, named '[Pup](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pup)' by O'Brien, who is eventually placed in a recursive program by O'Brien to keep it from running amok with the station.

Do we ever see or hear of this intelligent program again?  Do any episodes, expanded universe novels, or even fan fiction stories tell of the fate of O'Brien's unwanted pet 'dog'?

Comment: It's never mentioned again on-screen. In hindsight, one might imagine that it could have some connection to Vic Fontaine - perhaps it evolved into something that "broke out" of its doghouse and took over Fontaine's original personality subroutines to make him sentient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although it's never again mentioned in the TV series or films, the electronic virus known as the [Pup](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pup) does make a briefly appearance in the Trek Novel "[Star Trek: Deep Space Nine: Valhalla](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Valhalla)" when O'Brien releases it in order to distract an electronic entity known as **Enak** who's taken over control of the station...

> *Instructions were being countermanded. Signals were being blocked. New
> software subroutines were interfering with Enak's orders.*
>
> *Enak was
> losing control. The Pup was out of its doghouse and in Enak's virtual
> lap, and it had noticed that Enak was running the station. It wanted
> attention, wanted to play, so it was doing the cybernetic equivalent
> of jumping up and licking Enak's face.*
>
> *Distracted, countered by one
> of its own distant relatives, Enak was unable to dominate the computer
> systems; it was kept busy just dealing with the Pup's friendly
> overtures.*

At the end of the book, O'Brien returns it (apparently willingly) to its virtual 'doghouse'.

Comment: That...is adorable.  But are there any more references to Pup in any other works?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Not really. A couple of tangential references in various reference books like "Jadzia's Science Log" but nothing more than that

Comment: Darn...I was hoping Pup might've had a bit more closure than that, been released or matured into a full 'dog' at some point, that sort of thing. Well...I'll leave this open a little longer in case anyone digs up something really interesting.

Comment: @Zibbobz - I've had another hunt and there doesn't seem to be anything else. Time to close this, perhaps.

Comment: Agreed...that's too bad too.  I rather liked Pup.